# Magento does not use specified default value on attributes of type yes/no

Tags: attributes, magento-1, attribute-set, magento-1.9.4

I added a new attribute with `Default Value` set to `Yes`.

[image]

I added the attribute to my attribute set and edited the product, but it is set to `No` by default.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. It's a feature.
The default values serves as "default" from now on. It is not added to products existing prior to setting this default value.
If you create a new product, you should see the "yes" value selected.
There is no "out of the box" way of setting the default value to existing products.

Comment: Ok, I see. But they could have solved it in a way that the value is getting resetted to the default value if you add the attribute to a attribute set, but only on all the products which have the attribute set.

Comment: yes, it is possible. But it's not that easy. Anyway...that's irrelevant. The main idea is that it does not work the way you expected it to work. I had the same reaction the first time this happened to me.